# Do I need CSRF tokens for WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, security, authentication, token

If we are making a messenger program that requires a login and a password (and client and a server), then, I assume, we actually need a security token, exactly in the same way you would on the web.

In fact, if the client has a valid security token that it sends to the server to perform any action, then the fact that the token matched means that any action (even "delete my account") is valid (unless we have a really good hacker). Right?

Comment: Not to sound condescending, but please - go hire a security expert.  Your current understanding is extremely oversimplified.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on my flaws? P.S. this is a home project, not a business one. So, nothing is at stake here.

Comment: Well, for one thing, [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) is a very specific type of attack that targets *browsers* - that is, the web site sends code that the browser executes. I doubt your WinForms app contains a JavaScript engine, DOM, or other browser-like components.  Yes, security is still a concern, but your question is so very broad and the things you appear to be focused on are mostly irrelevant to the scenario you described.

Comment: There are *many* resources you can find on the web to get started with understanding security.  If I have to make one recommendation that's related to this line of questioning, I'd watch Troy Hunt's [Web Security and the OWASP Top 10](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/web-security-owasp-top10-big-picture) video course on Pluralsight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't. You only need csrf protection on web pages or http apis that are accessed using a web browser. It's a confused deputy attack, and the deputy is the browser. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_Deputy

If the remote login url is used by other apps that use a browser, then you would want csrf protection.

You do want to handle authentication and authorization correctly though. Please use a framework appropriate for your server environment. Hash passwords and use tls.